# Advantages and Disadvantages of Lossless compression?

Tags: compression, lossless

Can someone please tell me the pros and cons of lossless compression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The pros are that the fidelity will be better. The cons are more
>   subtle.

Read Details From [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-lossless-compression)